# a factorization of a finite group according to the Sylow subgroup s

Tags: group-theory

Let $ G $ be a finite group and  $|G|=p_1^{a_1 } p_2^{a_2}....p_n^{ a _n}$, where $p_i $ 's are distinct primes. Is this true that $ G=P_1 P_2... P_n$, where $ P_i $ is a Sylow $ p_i $ subgroup of $ G $?

Answer (score 1):

It follows from theorems of Philip Hall that such a factorization exists if and only if $G$ is solvable. This is treated in Gorenstein's bbook, for example.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to be careful here. It is true that the factorization exists for all orderings of the primes if and only if $G$ is solvable. But a factorization could exist for some orderings in other groups. For example, we can write $A_5=P_2P_3P_5$, but not $P_2P_5P_3$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your remark.